# setImageResource not working

Tags: android, imageview

I'm about to set an `ImageView` with `setImageResource`, but it's not working. nothing error too. and the logcat seems fine.

Here is my code  :

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_request, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View anotherView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_fragment_list_request,container,false);

    imgView = (CircleImageView)anotherView.findViewById(R.id.listPhoto);

    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pastel_red);
}
```

Considering that I called and declare the `ImageView` from another layout. Is at problem if I inflate 2 layouts just for set image for another layout ?

Anything wrong here?

Comment: are you adding anotherView layout to main layout after inflat and setting image resource ?

Comment: no , i inflate anotherView first then i set image.
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_request, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View anotherView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_fragment_list_request,container,false);

    imgView = (CircleImageView)anotherView.findViewById(R.id.listPhoto);

    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pastel_red);
}

Comment: You have to add anotherView otherwise it wont be shown.

Comment: i already add the anotherview, please check my post. but it still not working

Answer (score 1):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_request, container, false);
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(){
  ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getView().findById(R.id.layout_another_view); // need layout for anotherView in fragment_item_list_request.xml

  View anotherView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_fragment_list_request,container,false);
  imgView = (CircleImageView)anotherView.findViewById(R.id.listPhoto);
  imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pastel_red);

  layout.addView(anotherView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you do this instead:

```
 View anotherView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_fragment_list_request,null,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `return anotherView;` is missing in `onCreateView()`.